# Pod Install in Xcode project getting "command not found" error

Tags: xcode, git, bash

I cloned a large git repository and tried to run it, but I keep getting the error `No such module 'Google Maps.'` In the project folder, there is the normal Xcode files and then a file called Podfile, a file called Podfile.lock, and a folder called Pods, with a lot of folders inside it such as "Google Maps".  I think I need to run `pod install` from within the project folder, but when I go to Terminal, cd to the project folder, and type in pod install, I get the following error: `-bash: pod: command not found`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reinstalling Cocoapods:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Comment: Ah, my problem was that I never installed Cocoapods in the first place.  Thanks for the help!